# Understanding CSS child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm not able to use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` of the html structure below :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
    <div> Not child 1 </div>
    <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is select the 2nd `child_1` but I can't find how.
Is there any one have the answer for me?

Comment: That's off topic here mate. You should read some basic css tutorials.

Comment: .wrapper div.child_1:nth-child(2)

Answer (score 0):

You can't select `nth-of-type` for a class. You will have to target the `div` instead.

From MDN:

[nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

[nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
  <div> Not child 1 </div>
  <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` are pseudo classes (CSS3 Selectors Standards). As per CSS3 Standards pseudo class of elements are only accepted and pseudo class of classes is not possible.

Comment: @ovokuro : can you look for this https://jsfiddle.net/hv3vqazk/ .
I see that I can select by class here.

Comment: @freeman167 https://jsfiddle.net/afsz49e2/ -- you're not selecting the class. The class is of type `div`. That is being selected. See my fiddle...

Answer (score -1):

This will do your job.

```css
.wrapper .child_1:nth-child(3){
  background:red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
        <div> Not child 1 </div>
        <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
        <div class="child_1">Child 1</div>
    </div>
```

But if you want under stand the `child` selection.
There are several types of selection. like `nth-child` , `nth-of-type` , `first-child` and `last-child`

In this sample you cant use `nth-of-type` but can use the rest. If this is a long child group and you cant to select for the bottom you can use.

```
.wrapper .child_1:last-child{
  background:red;
}
```

and if you want to select the `second last child` you can use:

```
.wrapper .child_1:last-child(2){
  background:red;
}
```

this also goes from `top` using `first-child` Child selector. ty

Comment: While that will work, the selector is actually targetting the `div`, and not the class. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: He wanted to select the ` 2nd child_1` in the Q. so my answer is right.if the class is not there my answer will not work.Then why `downvote`, if the answer is right then please don't downvote you guys. Don't ruin the value of Stackoverflow.